# How to have multiple ~/.gitconfig instances under one user account?

Tags: git, github, version-control, environment-variables, tortoisegit

I need to have git setup on my system, where both GitHub and TortoiseGit have their own separate `~/.gitconfig` AKA global `.gitconfig` files. Because of the way git works, there doesnt seem to be anyway to do this?

Basically i need GitHub to look at one `.gitconfig` file by default, which would be the same info as my actual GitHub account, and then TortoiseGit somehow default to a completely separate `.gitconfig` file, completely separate of GitHubs's `.gitconfig` file.

If this can be achieved by some other means, like using a TortoiseGit alternative, thats fine as well, as long as it costs the same as TortoiseGit (free).

Comment: Maybe you could explain your actual goal. Are you trying to do both personal and professional development on one machine, for example?

Comment: That's basically the gist of it. I guess my question could be generalized a bit, trying to ignore specific git applications, and reworded basically as how can you have two global `.gitconfig` instances, that dont intermingle with each other at all?

Using say SVN or a different VCS provider for one type of work, and git for the work that goes to GitHub is obviously a solution, but its not ideal. So want to see how to do this with git. I couldnt mind any other questions addressing, zero interaction between two instances.

Comment: What are the differences between those two config files?

Comment: @FatherTimeWarner, I assume you know you can have per-repository values by omitting the `--global` flag?

Comment: @Chris, Yes. But when you open the `.git` file with Git Gui and go Edit > Options, the Global (All Repositories ) User Name, and Email Address fields are still being populated with the other works info. Or opening the `.git` file in Git Bash and going `$ git config --global --list` you see the other workspaces's info as well. This is what im trying to solve, making the other workspace's info not show up.

Comment: @FatherTimeWarner: Why don't you just remove all the workspace-specific settings from the global conf, and put it into the per-repository config file? You can even configure everything in the repository config, and not have any global config file.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of git will read the file `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` before reading `~/.gitconfig` - see the [manpage of git-](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)config.

You could have a separate git configuration unter, say, `~/project-bla/git/config`, and run `export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/project-bla/` in one terminal session. Then that session would always use that configuration. Note that settings in `~/.gitconfig` will overwrite these settings, so that file should only contain settings that apply everywhere.

However, this will only work for command-line git; I don't think there is such an option for TortoiseGit.

---

However, the easiest solution is to just configure everything in the repository-specific config file (under `mygitrepository1/.git/config`). These settings will not interfere with each other.

The only drawback is that you cannot share settings between some, but not all repositories - the settings in `~/.gitconfig` are for *all* repositories, and a repo config is *only* for that repository. If you want one config for repos a,b,c, and another for repos c,d,e, then you need to hack up something like the solution I outlined above.